# schema.org: How to properly markup foreign organization with offers

Tags: seo, schema.org

I want to collect useful resources regarding other businesses like - to give an example - groupon. Things like the address, founders and a general description of that company. Sometimes this description can be more specific though.

I also want to let the users rate this company and want to show interesting products or offers by that company - all on that same page.

How would you mark up this schema? I was looking at similar websites and they're all using different schemas:

http://www.topcashback.co.uk/ebookers/ (Schema: *Product*)
http://www.vouchercodes.co.uk/ebookers.com (Schema: *Organization*)
https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.ebookers.com (Schema: *LocalBusiness*)

Well *LocalBusiness* and *Product* seem wrong. Personally I'd go with *Organization*. But: if the whole page is of type *Organization*, how can I display *Product* or *Offer* inside? *Organizations* do not have properties for that. There are properties like *makesOffer* which should be inside an *Offer* and link to an *Organization*. But what if it's on the same page, inside the container which marks up an *Organization*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [`Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization) should be the main entity for your page. But ideally you would check for each organization if one of the subtypes applies and use it instead:

- If it’s a local business, use [`LocalBusiness`](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness).
- If it’s a corporation, use [`Corporation`](http://schema.org/Corporation).
- etc.

```html
<body vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="WebPage">
  <article property="mainEntity" typeof="Organization">
  </article>
</body>
```

Now you provide appropriate properties that reference other items which you want to say something about:

- With [`founder`](http://schema.org/founder), you reference the `Person`.
- With [`location`](http://schema.org/location), you reference the `PostalAddress`.
- With [`aggregateRating`](http://schema.org/aggregateRating), you reference the `AggregateRating`.
- etc.

```html
<body vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="WebPage">
  <article property="mainEntity" typeof="Organization">

    <div property="founder" typeof="Person"></div>
    <div property="location" typeof="PostalAddress"></div>
    <div property="aggregateRating" typeof="AggregateRating"></div>

  </article>
</body>
```

For representing "interesting products or offers", it depends on what it actually is:

- If you want to represent an offer the organization makes, [`makesOffer`](http://schema.org/makesOffer) is appropriate (it doesn’t link to an `Organization` but to an `Offer`), which from the `Offer` can reference the `Product`.
- If you want to represent a product the organization manufactured (no matter if the organization still offers it or not), you can use the reverse¹ of the [`manufacturer`](http://schema.org/manufacturer) property (because Schema.org doesn’t define an inverse property like "manufactured").

```html
<body vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="WebPage">
  <article property="mainEntity" typeof="Organization">

    <div property="founder" typeof="Person"></div>
    <div property="location" typeof="PostalAddress"></div>
    <div property="aggregateRating" typeof="AggregateRating"></div>

    <section>
      <div property="makesOffer" typeof="Offer"></div>
      <div rev="manufacturer" typeof="Product"></div> <!-- see an alternative below -->
    </section>

  </article>
</body>
```

An alternative to using the reverse of `manufacturer` is to use a `Product` item that references in `manufacturer` the `Organization` via its URI:

```html
<body vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="WebPage">
  <article property="mainEntity" typeof="Organization" resource="http://example.com/organizations/acme#this">

    <div typeof="Product">
      <link property="manufacturer" href="http://example.com/organizations/acme#this" />
    </div>

  </article>
</body>
```

---

¹ Microdata doesn’t offer a standard mechanism for this (but there is a proposal for `itemprop-reverse`). RDFa offers a mechanism (`rev`), but it’s not part of the subset RDFa Lite. JSON-LD offers a mechanism (`@reverse`).

Comment: Thanks! So if I got you right this means that a markup like this (in case of offers) is perfectly okay - each Offer will have the property makesOffer if it's inside an Organization, right? Like this: <div property="makesOffer" typeof="Offer"><meta property="price" content="1000.00" /></div>
<div property="makesOffer" typeof="Offer"><meta property="price" content="250.00" /></div>

Comment: @sleepless: Yes, that’s correct: [`Organization` `makesOffer` `Offer`]. For the other direction you’d use [`offeredBy`](http://schema.org/offeredBy): [`Offer` `offeredBy` `Organization`]. And if you have multiple offers, you use the property multiple times.

Comment: Thank you! That were really helpful and enlightening insights. I think I got it now.